How to move python files from the desktop to command prompt on a windows pc
C:\Users\ogunwusi kolawole>cd"C:\Users\ogunwusi kolawole\Desktop\Exercise Files\Chap01"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. I was trying to copy a programming tutorial exercise file from my desktop to the command prompt
I had already downloaded the programming tutorial files to my desktop, then I opened the command prompt and tried to move one of the files to the command prompt. But it gave me a syntax error code.

Try use this to move your file:
move "C:\path\to\source\*.txt" "C:\path\to\destination\"

Or if you wanna copy:
copy "C:\path\to\source\*.txt" "C:\path\to\destination\"

